# How to call the handler from separate class in android?

Tags: android, android-handler

In my application, am try to set an time out function i not able to call the **handler**  method in separate class.

**My Timeout Class**

```
 public class Timeout_function {

private Handler mHandler;
Activity activity;

public Timeout_function(Activity activity,Handler mHandler) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.mHandler = mHandler;
}

Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Test", 1000).show();
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

// just as an example, we'll start the task when the activity is started
public void onStart() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(myTask, 1000);
}

// at some point in your program you will probably want the handler to stop
// (in onStop is a good place)
public void onStop() {

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(myTask);
}
}
```

**Main class**
In main class i call the method in this way,but it shows error in run time,

```
Timeout_function timeout = new Timeout_function(this, mHandler);
    timeout.onStart();
```

how to call the method in main class.can any one know please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "handler function", because your `mHandler` is an object. Also, why do you think you can't call it? Plus, what's your architecture? Where is the code called which is supposed to interact with the `Handler`?

Comment: @ClassStacker how to start the interaction with handler.

Comment: I believe you have extracted this code from an Activity, where `onStart` would be called for you as part of the `Activity` lifecycle. It isn't doing this, so now you'll have to call `onStart` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a seperate class why you are not using [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)?

I would insist you to use Service and start your Runnable using Handler in `onStartCommand()` of Service by call `startService(intent);`

and you can stop the Runnable using Handler by placing it inside `onDestroy()` method of Service and calling by `stopService(intent)`.

This is what I had done and it works like a charm!

Comment: i am new to this concept,how to implement service in my application.

Comment: please google for that and you will find tons of examples for creating Service in Android.